# Arranging y-axis in descending order

Tags: r, plot, yaxis

I have an abacus plot in R that has the y-axis in descending order from the bottom. I need it descending from the top. The abacus_plot() uses base plot() variables. Seems straight forward, but I am coming up empty. My code:

```
library(glatos)
abacus_plot(detections_w_events,
            location_col= 'deploy_lat', ylab = 'Latitude',
            main='Detections by Station', x_res = "12 weeks", x_format = "%b-%y",
            col = detections_w_events$color)
```

The plot currently:

[image]

Comment: What package does `abacus_plot` come from?

Comment: The glatos package

Comment: Okay, looks like that's not from CRAN, can you direct us to where that package was downloaded from? (There's nothing preventing multiple packages existing out in the world with the same name, and sometimes that happens.)

Comment: https://github.com/ocean-tracking-network/glatos/wiki/installation-instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glatos::abacus_plot treats the y-axis values as text and by default it sorts levels in reverse alphabetical order along the y-axis from bottom to top. Although it seems counter-intuitive with a numeric value like latitude, you simply need to specify the unique y-axis levels (including order to be printed from bottom to top) and pass those to abacus_plot via the `locations` argument. This is explained further in ?abacus_plot.

So to answer your question, try:

```
# make vector of y-levels to display (with desired order, bottom-to-top along y)
my_locs <- sort(unique(detections_w_events$deploy_lat))

abacus_plot(detections_w_events,
            location_col= 'deploy_lat', 
            locations = my_locs,
            ylab = 'Latitude',
            main='Detections by Station', x_res = "12 weeks", x_format = "%b-%y",
            col = detections_w_events$color)
```